# User Tagged Questions

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

Stack Overflow should have a column named `User Tagged` that would show questions only from your Favorite Tags.

For example, say, I am interested in answering only questions related to PHP, C++ and HTML.

I should be able to access a page that has only questions related to these favorite tags of mine. So that way I won't have to go through questions of other languages I don't know.

What do you people think?

Comment: It's worth noting that even if you don't think you know the language you might be able to puzzle some things out, or learn something new. I'd rather have something to suppress my ignored tags... those are the ones I _really_ don't want to see.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Yes, but you can't expect a CSS designer to solve/correct a C# algorithm, right? Nice username, though.

Comment: I don't know what the CSS designed knows! I just know that I've found interesting things from randomly seeing post, which I wouldn't otherwise have found. On the other hand, I _don't_ want to see anything with Facebook in the tag name, so I suppress it. For finding questions to answer, this would certainly help a bit...

Comment: What you ask for was already suggested and declined.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, just read that now. Thanks for the link though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a search filter:

```
intags:mine
```

See the [search help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for more options.

Comment: It does work, but still, don't you think it's rather tedious to keep searching like that over and over?

Comment: @Eisa why don't you just create a bookmark? For example I don't ever type `intags:` I just click this favorite for all `sql-server*` tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server*

Comment: Set it up as a bookmark @Eisa? It's a feature-request, so this answer isn't a decline notice, or an implementation, it's more a statement that what you're requesting is semi-implemented already!